# pythonのコードをSublime Text3でビルドしたときに日本語が出力されないことがある

Tags: python, sublimetext

環境：Windows7(64bit), Python2.7, Sublime Text3

以下のようなコードをSublime Text3でビルドしてもSublime Text3の出力窓に何も出力されません（[Finished in *sec]は表示されますが）．エラーコメントは出ません．

```
# coding: utf-8

print "あいうえお"
```

> [Finished in 0.1s]

ただし，いつも出力されないわけではなく，print "日本語"の前にprint "英数字"を書くとなぜか日本語も出力されます．

```
# coding: utf-8

print "test"
print "あいうえお"
```

> test
>   あいうえお
>   [Finished in 0.2s]

しかし，順番を逆にするとまたなにも出力されなくなります．

```
# coding: utf-8

print "あいうえお"
print "test"
```

> [Finished in 0.2s]

---

また，日本語と日本語の間に英数字を入れても何も出力されません．print "英数字"以下が出力されるようになるわけではなく，はじめにprint "英数字"を入れた場合だけ出力されるようになります．

```
# coding: utf-8

print "あいうえお"
print "test"
print "かきくけこ"
```

> [Finished in 0.1s]

```
# coding: utf-8

print "test"
print "あいうえお"
print "かきくけこ"
```

> test
>   あいうえお
>   かきくけこ
>   [Finished in 0.2s]

この現象はCなどの他の言語では起きません．また，write()でファイル書き込みをした場合は普通に書き込まれます．
一応，日本語入力関係パッケージのインストール・設定はできているつもりです．必要であれば入っているPackage，UserのSettingsの一覧を書きますので言ってください．